# How to use CSS background-attachment in <img> tag?

Tags: css, image, background-image

How would you use the CSS style `background-attachment` and apply it to an `<img>` tag?

```
<img src="ok.jpg">
```

CSS:

```
img {
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: `background-attachment` does not strictly apply to images...but rather elements with `background-images` [**MDN Link**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment)...so it's not really clear wha you are asking.

Comment: Is there a workaround this? What could you do to achieve the same affect on an `<img>` without using `background-image`?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do...perhaps you could [edit] your question with more information and meaningful code.

Comment: @Ozzy Check my answer, but I'm not sure that I understood your question correctly, because bit unclear.

Answer (score 20):

Adding this in case anyone else gets here looking to replicate the behavior of `background-attachment: fixed;` while using an `img` tag in HTML.

You cannot use background properties on an `<img>` tag as requested, but you CAN replicate it's behavior by using `position: fixed` on the image and `clip-path` on it's container.

Example:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px 10px;
  clip-path: inset(0);
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cant do that. First of all `background-attachment` is CSS "function", and you can give that ONLY for `background-image`.
You can also get similar view, with `position:fixed` to img.

```
img {
     position: fixed;
}
```

Try [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ye7qwj1p/)

Answer (score 2):

Well, background-attachment is not going to work the image src. You'd have to have something like this:

```
<div class="img"></div>
```

CSS

```
.img { background-image: url('ok.jpg'); background-attachment: fixed; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't generally use background-attachment for an `<img>` tag.

What you actually want to do is set your image as a background for something like the body or a div and then set the attachment to fixed.

```
<style>
    .bg-image {
        background-image: url(ok.jpg);
        background-attachment:fixed;
    }
</style>

<div class='bg-image'></div>
```

Or something along those lines.

You'll probably want to set the `height` or `min-height` for the div also so that you can ensure it shows up.

Also you might want to play with the background-repeat styles, by default it will repeat both on x and y.