# Is there a property that does to the image tag what "background-attachement: fixed" does to a background image?

Tags: css

I've spent the past 60 minutes looking for a property that does to the image tag what "background-attachement: fixed" does to a background image.

I know for a fact this property exists, I used it once 6 months ago. I found out about it when I found out about "object-fit: cover" for the image tag.

I've no idea how to further describe it. I'm hoping that someone in here knows what I'm talking about.

Here's a video explanation: https://www.loom.com/share/b5f7652d60994d9392c7fa00dc8b260e

Comment: [object-position property MDN WebDocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position)

Comment: So you want a fixed image that stays there when you scroll?

Comment: @tacoshy nope, that's not it

Comment: @Matthias I want the same effect that "background-attachement: fixed;" does to a background image, but I want to use it on the image tag instead of using it on a div that has a background image. I'm honestly starting to think I'm crazy and the property that I'm looking for doesn't even exist at this point 

Comment: If you have no idea what I'm yapping about, here's a video explanation: https://www.loom.com/share/b5f7652d60994d9392c7fa00dc8b260e

Comment: Maybe position:fixed + clip-path: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68466386/2418224

Comment: @juzraai that achieves the effect, yes. But then again, so does "background-attachement: fixed;". I'm still willing to bet there is one obscure, new property that does the effect in just one line. And, at this point, I'm just being stubborn about finding it tbh.

Comment: Maybe you had this in mind [Background-attachment:fixed equivalent for IMGs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46896868/background-attachmentfixed-equivalent-for-imgs)

Comment: Or `position: sticky` I know that apple uses `position: sticky` to achieve similar effects on their website. But `sticky` only works for that purpose only on very limited use-cases.

Answer (score 0):

At this point, finding that property (that may not even exist and I'm wrong about it) is a time sink. So, I'm giving up and wrapping this up.

There are 2 options to achieve the effect.

1. Use a background-image on a div tag with "background-attachement:fixed" like I did in this loom video https://www.loom.com/share/b5f7652d60994d9392c7fa00dc8b260e
2. Use the clip-path trick mentioned in this other question [How to use CSS background-attachment in <img> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33550450/how-to-use-css-background-attachment-in-img-tag/68466386#68466386)

I personally will go for #1, because it is cleaner to implement in my Tailwind + Next.js codebase.

But #2 works just as well and it allows you to use the image tag. Using the image tag has the benefits of easy lazy-loading and slightly better SEO.